# Biopython: Cant use .count() for biopython

Tags: biopython

My goal here is to receive the amount of time 'g' appears in a DNA sequence.

I imported a DNA sequence via Biopython using list comprehension

```
seq = [record for record in SeqIO.parse('sequences/hiv.gbk.rtf', 'fasta')]
```

I then tried using the .count() method on the newly created list comp variable

```
print(seq.count('g'))
```

I get an error that reads

> NotImplementedError: SeqRecord comparison is deliberately not
>   implemented. Explicitly compare the attributes of interest.

Anyone know what the dealio is? Biopython's manual says all standard python methods should work.

Comment: Please don't cross post your question on biostars and scicomp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply `count` to a list. You would to need to apply it to the sequence of each element, e.g.

```
print(seq[0].seq.count('g'))
```

or if you want to get the sum of all sequences

```
print(sum([s.seq.count('g') for s in seq]))
```

---

Here is a minimal working example

```
from Bio import SeqIO

txt = """>gnl|TC-DB|O60669|2.A.1.13.5 Monocarboxylate transporter 2 - Homo sapiens (Human).
MPPMPSAPPVHPPPDGGWGWIVVGAAFISIGFSYAFPKAVTVFFKEIQQIFHTTYSEIAW
>gnl|TC-DB|O60706|3.A.1.208.23 ATP-binding cassette sub-family C member 9 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ABCC9 PE=1 SV=2
MSLSFCGNNISSYNINDGVLQNSCFVDALNLVPHVFLLFITFPILFIGWGSQSSKVQIHH
>gnl|TC-DB|O60721|3.A.1.208.23 Sodium/potassium/calcium exchanger 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=SLC24A1 PE=1 SV=1
MGKLIRMGPQERWLLRTKRLHWSRLLFLLGMLIIGSTYQHLRRPRGLSSLWAAVSSHQPI
>gnl|TC-DB|O60779|2.A.1.13.5 Thiamine transporter 1 (THTR-1) (ThTr1) (Thiamine carrier 1) (TC1) - Homo sapiens (Human).
MDVPGPVSRRAAAAAATVLLRTARVRRECWFLPTALLCAYGFFASLRPSEPFLTPYLLGP"""

filename = 'sequences.fa'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)

seqs = [record for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta')]

print(sum([s.seq.count('P') for s in seqs]))    
>>> 21

print(seqs[0].seq.count('P'))
>>> 9
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any reason why .count() won't work when importing a file without list comprehension such as                                                     rec = SeqIO.parse("sequences/hiv.gbk.rtf", "fasta")

Comment: `count` is a method commonly used for `strings` and `lists`. The makers of BioPython didn't implement it for `SeqIO` objects. My guess would be that the results would be ambiguous.